# Как узнать реальное время работы алгоритма по функции сложности?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть алгоритм  сложности `O(n*Log(n))`, есть ЭВМ с процессором 2.1Ггц.
Проблема: как вычислить время работы алгоритма на машине если мы знаем `N`?

Как я понял, функция сложности нужна как раз для того, чтобы охарактеризовать время работы алгоритма.

При вычислении времени работы алгоритма по функции сложности меня смущает то, что вот такие вещи не учитывается:

```
a = a+b;// O(1) 1с
b = b+1;// O(1) 1с
```

Итого время выполнения этих операций равно 2с, функция сложности равна O(1).
По функции сложности как-то не удается получить время выполнения алгоритма.
Возможно ли d принципе определить время работы алгоритма, зная его сложность?

Comment: Время работы будет очень сильно зависеть от конкретного процессора. Одни и те же операции разные процессоры, работающие на одной частоте выполняют с разной скоростью. И играет роль не только операция, но и комбинации операций. Две независящие операции выполненные в разном порядке приводят на современных процессорах к разному времени выполнения из за внутренний оптимизации в процессорах. И тактовая частота имеет к этому очень отдаленное отношение. Функция сложности дает только отдаленное понимание о количестве операций и может использоваться только в сравнительных целях для оценки алгоритмов

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Это невозможно. "Функция сложности" `O(f(N))`, как Вы её назвали, отвечает на вопрос о том, с какой скоростью растёт число операций алгоритма (`f(N)`), когда `N` устремляется к бесконечности. То есть, например, если сортировка имеет сложность `O(N^2)`, то значит при удвоении размера массива Вы получите учетверение числа операций, необходимых для сортировки, при условии, что `N` - это очень большое число. Никакого отношения ко времени работы данная функция не имеет. `O(1)` Означает, что скорость работы функции не зависит от размера входного параметра `N`, при этом время работы может быть от нуля секунд до миллиарда лет (и больше).

Ещё Вам следует понять разницу между алгоритмом, и программой, его реализующей. Сложность алгоритма - это одно, а скорость программы - это совсем другое. Эти величины могут быть связаны, но далеко не всегда очевидным образом.

Подробности (но весьма сложные) можно прочитать [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Answer (score 1):

Сложность говорит не о самом времени, а о том, как оно будет меняться с изменением *n*. Вы можете замерить время работы вашей программы на целевой машине для некоторого конкретного (например, небольшого) *n*, и зная сложность, оценить, сколько времени займет работа при других (например, очень больших) значениях.